# What is the integration of $\sqrt {\tan x+\cot x}$?

Tags: integration, functions

I saw a question about what would be the integration of $\sqrt {\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}$!  Well, it was not that tough.

But after that I thought what would be the integral of $\sqrt {\tan x+\cot x}$. And with my mathematical knowledge I couldn't solve it. (I am a 12th grader)

When I tried to do it the wolfram integral calculator, it did give some result but which was out of my grasp(Hyper geometric function!!!). Here is the link:

http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=Sqrt%5Bcot+x%2Btanx%5D&random=false

So can you give me an answer that I can grasp?

Comment: Some integrals simply can't be solved in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 2):

Many integrals can not be solved using elementary functions such as powers, trigonometry and exponentials and their inverses. For some such integrals which come up often Mathematicians have made up new functions which are defined in terms of the integral. These functions can still be studied and their properties examined and other applications found.

The Hypergeometric function is an example of such a function. It can be defined in several different ways (including infinite sums as well as integrals). A definition involving integrals is:

$$_2F_1(a,b;c;x)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(b-c)}\int_0^1\frac{t^{b-1}(1-t)^{c-b-1}}{(1-tx)^a}dt$$

, where $\Gamma(x)$ is the Gamma function which is like factorial but works on all numbers not just natural numbers.

So your result of:

$$-\frac{2 _2F_1\left(\frac14,\frac34;\frac54;\cos^2x\right)}{\sqrt[4]{\sin^2x}\sqrt{\csc x\sec x}}$$

could be written as:

$$-\frac{2 \frac{\Gamma(\frac54)}{\Gamma(\frac34)\Gamma(-\frac12)}\int_0^1\frac{1}{t^{1/4}(1-t)^{1/2}(1-\cos^2x\cdot t)^{1/4}}dt}{\sqrt[4]{\sin^2x}\sqrt{\csc x\sec x}}$$

Comment: May I make a comment ? Your answer is very general and nobody can object anything. But, as you are a teacher, you know that one of the best teaching methods is by using thorough examples. I am not certain that giving to a 12th grader the reference to the complicated Wolfram explanations about (complicated in themselves) hypergeometric function(s) is the best to do (in particular, the definition by an integral has to be found very late). There are simpler examples that you can give. Gamma function, that I mention in my answer, depending on a **single** parameter is much more understandable.

Comment: The link is there if he wants to read more but I do agree its too technical - I did/do intend to come back and add/edit more but its been a busy day. I think the valuable point to learn from this question is that most integrals are not nice and thats the is important when compared to differentiation where everything works but can be messy. You get a lot of questions "I can't seem to do <insert question they made up>" and more often than not the answer is "You can't do it.".

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a rather simple answer if you consider a definite integral instead of an indefinite integral (a primitive) that looks very complicated.

In fact a small calculation gives $\sqrt{\tan x+\cot x}=1/\sqrt{\cos(x) \sin(x)}$.

Taking bounds that are natural (tangent is not defined in $\pi/2$, cotangent is not defined in $0$)

$$\tag{1}I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(x)^{-1/2} \sin(x)^{-1/2}dx$$

This is the area of the region under the curve represented below. Though not bounded, its value is finite as we are going to see it.

[image]

Now, have a look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) where the $Beta$ integral is defined. It is a rather important tool, extending to a continuous context the - inverse of - binomial coefficients, whence their names). The general Beta integral depends on two parameters ; it may be defined by:

$\tag{2}B(x,y)=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(x)^{2x-1} \sin(x)^{2y-1}dx$

The connection between (1) and (2) is made by taking $x=y=1/4$,  giving:

$$I=\dfrac{1}{2}B\left(\dfrac{1}{4},\dfrac{1}{4}\right)\approx3.70815$$

(the last value has been obtained with Mathematica ; in fact, all scientific computer software are able to compute this kind of integral).

Remark : one may wonder how this $B\left(\dfrac{1}{4},\dfrac{1}{4}\right)$ can be computed ; it is "very simple":

$$B\left(\dfrac{1}{4},\dfrac{1}{4}\right)=\dfrac{(-3/4)! \times (-3/4)!}{(-1/2)!}$$

where the "!" designates an extension of the classical "factorial" symbol.

A last remark: $(-1/2)!=\sqrt{\pi}$. Astonishing, no ? In fact, it is the Gamma function which is hidden behind the factorial notation. I advise you to learn what this function is, and what are its properties (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function): it is not difficult, and may be very rewarding.

Wishing, as you are a 12th grader, that it has not been too difficult, and maybe that it has given you some appetite for your forthcoming maths !

Answer (score 0):

tan x + cot x = t^2. (tan x)^2 + (cot x)^2 + 2 = t^4.
((sec x )^2 + (cosec x)^2)dx = 2tdt = (2 + (tan x)^2 + (cot x)^2 )dx = t^4 dx.
You can substitute and simplify from here.

Comment: Your $\csc^2x$ term should have a negative in front it. Also can you please indicate how the substitution and following integral is simple. Writing $\sec^2x-\csc^2x$ in terms of $t$ doesn't look straightforward. All other methods suggest it in very difficult.

Comment: I apologise for the mistake. Does not seem to simplify.